# How can I call NSStringFromProtocol with a Swift protocol?

Tags: swift, swift2

Assuming some

```
protocol MyCoolProtocol {
   ....
}
```

the following code refuses to compile (as of Swift 2.1):

```
let protocolName = NSStringFromProtocol(MyCoolProtocol)
```

because `MyCoolProtocol` is not of type `Protocol`. (This, at first glance, seems really weird, but if you dig enough it [unfortunately] makes sense)

How can I get the name of my Swift `protocol` in a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1. The most common suggestion I can find is to declare your `protocol` as `@objc`. This seems odd when you have no intention of referring to this `protocol` from Objective-C code.
2. You can use `let protocolName = String(MyCoolProtocol)`. As of the current version of Swift, this gives exactly what you'd expect (`"MyCoolProtocol"`) and is still checked at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I accomplished it:

```swift
let protocolString = String("\(MyProtocol.self)")
```